# Cannot add constraint to DataTable which is a child table in two nested relations

Tags: c#-2.0

```
void ReadXMLData()
    {
        string filePath = @"D:\XMLFiles\cms.xml";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.EnforceConstraints = false;
        ds.ReadXml(filePath);
    }
```

When I read the above xml file I got the error: Cannot add constraint to DataTable which is a child table in two nested relations.

Kindly help me that how can I overcome the mentioned DataSet exception?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

do you have any control over the XML formatting? I believe XML where child nodes have the same names as ancestor nodes are not fully supported. Would that be your case?

Edit: this might be helpfull: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/dataset.aspx. (MC++, but the same principles appy).

Answer (score 0):

xml data is loaded into VS.NET 2005 xml editor

right clicking "view data grid" yields
"Cannot add constraint to datatable 'xxx' which is a child table in two nested relations"

HOWEVER if you move element  before  and , or if you delete  or 
right clicking "view data grid" properly displays the data grid. Note that  and  are indentical.